# How do I create a new VS code window without any extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have created a lot of Windows. Now I need a window with no extension. How do I create it

Comment: you can disable all extensions from the Extension Bar

Comment: thanks you @Kiril  ,I found the answer https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions

Answer (score 6):

Try File -> New Window or `Ctrl + Shift + N`

Or if you want to start VSCode without any exentions loaded then you can use the command line `code --disable-extensions`